# What does term "Legally Guarded" mean?

Tags: terminology

When asked your legal relation to another What does the  term "Legally Guarded" mean? As opposed to Legal Guardian?

Comment: Where did you see this phrase? I can find no reference to it in Google other than this question! A guardian has responsibility for a young person whose parents are dead or considered unable to fulfil the parental role; that person is called a **ward**.